# Why won't an element of my array display after being called the second or so time?

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with my Point of Sales program for a project in C programming. The problem is that whenever I try to call for the first order the second or so time in my array, it won't appear. However, if I were to call a different element/order from that array a second or so time, it appears. I don't understand why this happens. Here is the function for it:

```
int orderTaking()
{
    int i, j, cash, cashChange, order, option, choice, additionalChoice, quantity, total, finalTotal, additionalPrice = 0;
    int price[20] = {20 , 80 , 85 , 90 , 90 , 150 , 100 , 120 , 130 , 120 , 150, 120 , 110, 150, 160, 60, 60, 30, 20, 15};
    int receipt[20];
    char orders[21][30] = { "Tiny Burger", "Jumbo Burger", "Turkey Burger", "Chicken Burger", "BBQ Burger" , "Banquet Burger" , "Chili Burger" , "California Burger" , "Juicy Lucy" , "Rice Burger" , "Salmon Burger" , "Slopper" , "Slug Burger" , "Veggie Burger" , "Teriyaki Burger" , "Big Fries" , "Mojos" , "Large Drinks" , "Water" , "Extra Cheese" };
    char orderChoice;

    i = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\tWhat is your order? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n\tYou chose %s!", orders[choice - 1]);
        printf ("\n\tEnter quantity of order: ");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);

        receiptInfo[i].quantity = quantity;
        receiptInfo[i].order = choice;
        receipt[i] = choice;

        total = (price[choice -1] * quantity);
        additionalPrice += total;
        receiptInfo[i].receiptTotal = total;
        i++;

        printf("\n\tYour total is %d PHP", additionalPrice);
        printf("\n\tWould you like to order again? (Y/N): ");
        scanf("%s", &orderChoice);
        if (orderChoice == 'Y') 
            continue;
        else if (orderChoice == 'N')    
            break;  
        else 
            printf("\n\tInvalid Input, Please try again!");
            additionalPrice = 0;
            continue;
    }
```

Comment: I just refactored someone's code for a virtually identical problem yesterday. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031364/c-ordersystem-for-fastfood-project/61032427#61032427

Comment: @Craig Estey 

So I just tried out changing i=1 to i=0, the element still won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong starting index for your array. The *first* element [at index *zero*] will *never* be filled in.

You are starting with:

```
i = 1;
```

Change this to:

```
i = 0;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> So I just tried out changing i=1 to i=0, the element still won't appear.

Without posting your entire program, it's difficult to determine what is wrong. Also, what you posted won't compile cleanly because there is no `return` statement. And, you have many unused variables.

I'd recompile with `-Wall -O2` and fix all the warnings/errors.

But, one thing I did notice is:

```
if (orderChoice == 'Y')
    continue;
else if (orderChoice == 'N')
    break;
else
    printf("\n\tInvalid Input, Please try again!");
    additionalPrice = 0;
    continue;
```

But, the indenting is misleading. Done correctly we have:

```
if (orderChoice == 'Y')
    continue;
else if (orderChoice == 'N')
    break;
else
    printf("\n\tInvalid Input, Please try again!");
additionalPrice = 0;
continue;
```

This probably doesn't change the outcome but I believe you meant:

```
if (orderChoice == 'Y')
    continue;
else if (orderChoice == 'N')
    break;
else {
    printf("\n\tInvalid Input, Please try again!");
    additionalPrice = 0;
    continue;
}
```

With further cleanup/simplification:

```
if (orderChoice == 'Y')
    continue;
if (orderChoice == 'N')
    break;
printf("\n\tInvalid Input, Please try again!");
additionalPrice = 0;
```

So, `additionalPrice`, which is a running sum, will be reset to zero if any invalid input is given. Is this really what you want?